# Javascript times the contents of div A with div B and display in div C (triggered when div A is changed)

Tags: javascript

What I need is to listen for changes to the div "qty_a-row" then times the value of div "qty_a-row" with the value of div "price-a-row" and put the answer in div "sub-total-a-row"

Here is what I have tried..

```
<div id="qty-a-row" contenteditable='true'></div><br>
<div id="price-a-row" contenteditable='true'></div><br>
<div id="sub-total-a-row" contenteditable='true'></div>
```

```js
var contents = $(".qty-a-row").html();
$(".qty-a-row").blur(function () {
  if (contents != $(this).html()) {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty-a-row").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("price-a-row").value);
    document.getElementById("sub-total-a-row").innerText = (x * y);
  }
});
```

For testing, I enter a value into the div "price-a-row" then enter a quantity in and the result should show but its now showing.

JSF added https://jsfiddle.net/eLgrmbuj/

Comment: Hard to help without some relevant html to test it with. Also beyond showing what you tried, what is or isn't happening? What errors are thrown? Note that multiplication operator is `*` not `x`

Comment: the html is simply  <div id="div-id"  contenteditable='true'></div> where div-ids are qty-a-row,  price-a-row & sub-total-a-row as above. for getting this working thats all I need but once working price-a-row will be from a database, sub-total-a-row will be calculated and the only user input will be qty-a-row via content editable.

Comment: changed (x x y) to (x * y) error I'm getting at the moment is Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code currently.  The error has to do with some code you aren't sharing.

Comment: @GirkovArpa added to OP but they are just divs and I am getting error Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break??

Comment: Found a missing " and added, this cleared the Uncaught SyntaxError but im now getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined code is as above in my updated OP.

Comment: JSFiddle added https://jsfiddle.net/eLgrmbuj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery but you did not include it in the page which is why you get `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
You're using a class selector to select your div for the blur event `.` is for class `#` is for id
Divs do not have `value` properties you'll have to use `textContent` to get the numbers

```js
var contents = $("#qty-a-row").html();
$("#qty-a-row").blur(function () {
  if (contents != $(this).html()) {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty-a-row").textContent);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("price-a-row").textContent);
    document.getElementById("sub-total-a-row").textContent = (x * y);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qty-a-row" contenteditable='true'>2</div><br>
<div id="price-a-row" contenteditable='true'>1.00</div><br>
<div id="sub-total-a-row" contenteditable='true'></div>
```

---

See below for a version without jQuery

```js
var contents = document.getElementById("qty-a-row").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("qty-a-row").addEventListener('blur', function () {
  if (contents != this.innerHTML) {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty-a-row").textContent);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("price-a-row").textContent);
    document.getElementById("sub-total-a-row").textContent = (x * y);
  }
});
```

```html
   
<div id="qty-a-row" contenteditable='true'>2</div><br>
<div id="price-a-row" contenteditable='true'>1.00</div><br>
<div id="sub-total-a-row" contenteditable='true'></div>
```

Comment: RE: jQuery I did not know this (I have very limited knowledge) I was actually trying to only use vanilla javascript. Thank you for the info regarding value vs textContent I will update this part but given you've said im using Jquery I guess until I figure out how to change to vanilla javascript i'll always have an issue?

Comment: @GlenKeybit I added a version without jQuery

Answer (score 0):

make the div inputs and use the value property,
fix the jquery selectors
fix the event binding syntax
remove the if condition, don't really know what that was about

```
<input id="qty-a-row" contenteditable="true" value="2" /><br />
<input id="price-a-row" contenteditable="true" value="1.00" /><br />
<div id="sub-total-a-row" contenteditable="true"></div>

$("#qty-a-row, #price-a-row").on('change', function () {
    var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("qty-a-row").value);
    var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("price-a-row").value);
    document.getElementById("sub-total-a-row").innerText = (x * y);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6sh587ve/4/